# Incorrect syntax error when accessing remote stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, asp.net, sql

StackOverflow - I'm still trying to deploy this site, but with every problem I solve, another arises. Anyways - I've set up the database at my hosting to allow remote connections, and it is running Sql Server 2005. On my development machine, I am working with Sql Server 2008.

I've installed the asp.net schema on my hosted database, and have created several users from the ASP.NET web administration interface, as well as tested that the login works. Running the application locally with the remote connection string nets the same results. However - I'm able to run my scripts and generate my tables and stored procedures without errors - but when the site is run I get the following error on all of my .aspx pages that try to access a stored procedure:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Incorrect syntax near 'LoadProfileData'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near 'LoadProfileData'.

Source Error:

Line 62:             adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@ProfessionalName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = professionalName;
Line 63:             DataSet profile = new DataSet();
Line 64:             adapter.Fill(profile, "Profile");
Line 65:             return profile;
Line 66:         }
```

Is this a possible Sql 2005 vs 2008 issue? I'm hoping someone else has seen this issue in a similar scenario and can point me in the right direction. The server is running asp.net 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5 and IIS 7.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think we really need to see the proc, the message you post suggests it's a syntax error, perhaps you are using sql2008 features in the proc. 
If you're running on SQL 2008 in development try setting the database compatability level to 9 and see if you get the same error.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but this is a duplicate question migrated from server fault. I needed to add "exec" before my procedure call in the DAL.